# PHP preg_match for phone numbers

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to preg_match phone numbers which can be in any of these formats:

1) 51113333 (8-digit without any space in between)

2) 5111 3333 (8-digit with a space in between)

3) 5111-3333 (8-digit with a hyphen in between)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This'll do it.

```
\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}
```

### [demo](http://rubular.com/r/oIRibuEg05)

Note last example.  It's much more complicated if this is going to be in other text, like "somestuff12345678otherstuff" because you have to check that the character before and after aren't numbers.  Let me know if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match( "/[^\d]\d{4}[- ]?\d{4}[^\d]/", $number );
```

I believe. Can't remember if preg_match supports {4} or if you need \d\d\d\d